# HTML5 - Video tags play video but not audio

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am using a video tag for importing videos using PHP. But I am facing an audio issue. I have used so many codes like:

`<video controls>  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" ></video>`

`<video controls src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" ></video>`

Comment: Have you ... turned your volume up?

Comment: Are your speakers turned on? Does the video file actually have an audio track? Yes it does

Comment: As per you, I have turned the volume up and also check the audio track. But still, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem may lies on your speaker. This is because I tried running your code and the video and the audio seems to work perfectly fine. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on your browser to check if the browser support the audio video codec format.

```
<video controls width="550">

    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">

    Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos.
</video>
```